# Table and counter doesn't appear

Tags: latex

Missing, "Table *n*"? I don't know why this is happening with the `longtable`.

**Looks like this:**
[image]

**Latex: Reproducable Example**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pifont,mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{longtable}

\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }

\newlist{RQ}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[RQ,1]{before={\itshape\textit},label=\textbf{RQ\arabic*},wide=0pt}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions]{font=\textit,label=\textbf{RQ1.\arabic*},wide=0pt}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{LightYellow}{RGB}{255, 215, 100}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\enotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{%
  \raggedright
  \leftskip=1.8em
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\theenmark. \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\baselineskip}}%
}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{syntaxred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} 

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}
        \caption{Summary of the related work}\label{tab:summary-related-works}\\
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{ | p{2.5cm} | p{6cm} | p{6cm} |}
        \hline  
        Reference~\# & Study overview & Relevant Findings \\ \hline  
        Michael et al. 2021 [1] & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & 
        
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, label={--}]
            \item Lorem Ipsum
            \item Lorem Ipsum
        \end{itemize}
        \\ \hline
       Sherryl et al. 2021 [2] & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Hello \\ \hline
        
        Rubin and Anderson [3] & 
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        & Hello \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: That's all the Latex code, what do you need?

Comment: The used packages. :-)

Comment: ... a compilable document, starting with a class, would be nice so we can directly reproduce your problem without having to guess all the missing fragments.

Comment: If I combine your code fragments as they are, I get an error `Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\caption): c' used. \caption` instead of just a missing numbering.

Comment: That's too many packages. *Minimal* reproducible example! `\documentclass` is also missing. Plus any macros you defined that could mess with things. I need to be able to copy and paste your code, run it, and see what you get.

Comment: @Robert, `Article`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I received the same.

Comment: This is the setup: `documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}`

Comment: @AlbinM In this case you are asking the complete wrong question. You should ask how to fix the error instead of looking into what might or might not be a valid pdf. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output

Comment: @AlbinM Please add ONE single codeblock to your question which has everything necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, how can this be **Fixed**?

Comment: @AlbinM First step in fixing: add a [mre] to your question which we can directly use, without us having to puzzle anything together

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, POSTED MVP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `longtable` *instead* of `tabular` and not warp your tabular in a longtable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pifont,mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{longtable}

\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }

\newlist{RQ}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[RQ,1]{before={\itshape\textit},label=\textbf{RQ\arabic*},wide=0pt}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions]{font=\textit,label=\textbf{RQ1.\arabic*},wide=0pt}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{LightYellow}{RGB}{255, 215, 100}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\enotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{%
  \raggedright
  \leftskip=1.8em
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\theenmark. \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\baselineskip}}%
}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | p{2.5cm} | p{6cm} | p{6cm} |}
        \caption{A summary of the related work}\label{tab:summary-related-works}\small\\
        \hline  
        Reference~\# & Study overview & Relevant Findings \\ \hline  
        Michael et al. 2021 [1] & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & 
        
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, label={--}]
            \item Lorem Ipsum
            \item Lorem Ipsum
        \end{itemize}
        \\ \hline
        Sherryl et al. 2021 [2] & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. & Hello \\ \hline
        
        Rubin and Anderson [3] & 
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        & Hello \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**Results:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me!

Comment: @AlbinM You're welcome!

Comment: @AlbinM If you are not happy with the content of the screenshot, please provide an alternative file, but don't just remove it from the answer!